# Grails 3.1.1 - Dirty checking not working when model class extends another groovy class

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-3.1, dirty-tracking

I have a domain class which extends another groovy class with same name but in different package in a different library.

The problem is when I modify instances on the domain class, it is not marked as dirty & hence changes are not persisted.

I have read that grails 3 release has some enhancements to dirty checking & this could be a bug or I am missing something.

New objects are saved properly without any issues, I have used **isDirty()** method on modified domain object as well as modified properties & both return **false**. Objects are attached to the session, confirmed with **isAttached()**.

To reproduce, I created a test project with following code & tried updating the object from default grails views that are generated using scaffolding, but still the changes are not persisted.

**Note:** I have done similar stuff in Grails 2.4 & it used to work.

**Domain class is as follows:**

```
package com.perseus

class Derived extends Base{

    static constraints = {
        name blank: false, nullable: false
    }

}
```

**Base class in src/main/groovy**:

```
package com.perseus

class Base implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L

    String name

}
```

**Controller**

```
package com.perseus

class DerivedController {

    static scaffold = Derived

}
```

**Link to github [project](https://github.com/Pritesh-Mhatre/grails).**

**Isssue**: Model is not marked dirty, even if it has been modified. This happens when a model class extends another groovy class.

How to reproduce:

1. Run the app.
2. Create a new model object (model name is Derived)
3. Modify the object using edit view & click Update.
4. You will see that modifications are not persisted.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to know what is wrong.  There are any number of explanations for why an object might not be considered dirty after attempting to update it.

Comment: I will try to reproduce it with a very small project & share a link. There is nothing much to add to be honest, my views are created using scaffolding & when I update the domain, the changes are not persisted. Give me some time, I will get back with more details.

Comment: Updated the question with sample code, also gave steps to reproduce the problem & github link of the project.

Comment: @PriteshMhatre Please provide your object persistence code.

Comment: @NitinDhomse I reproduced the issue on a small test project shared a link of the github project, I am using scaffolding. Link: https://github.com/Pritesh-Mhatre/grails

Comment: I'm not able to find expected code there, there is no service directory. Instead of github link you can just provide the code here.

Comment: For some reason my git is unable to commit following EMPTY directories (taglib, services, utils). But you can clone and run the app, it works.

Comment: @NitinDhomse I have added the controller code here as well, that is all I have. Rest of the files are default ones, generated by create-app command.

Comment: @PriteshMhatre I was asking about service call of data persistence where you have written the domainObject.save().

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161493/discussion-between-pritesh-mhatre-and-nitin-dhomse).

Comment: Try with it.save(flush : true, failOnError: true);

Comment: I have tried that, it doesnt work. Problem is with dirty checking, I have seen in debug mode that the object is not marked as dirty.

Comment: @PriteshMhatre "For some reason my git is unable to commit following EMPTY directories" - Git doesn't support empty directories.  That is by design.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a reference [here](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10847) which explains the reason for failure to update dirty check status.

I added **@DirtyCheck** annotation and it solved the problem.

However this has a negative impact on the design of our libraries.

We have separate projects for each category:

- Business model classes
- Business logic classes
- User Interface

The idea is to have modules completely independent of each other. So model & business logic liraries can be used by any UI technology. Now the problem is that I had to add gorm dependency to my business model project for the annotation.

```
compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:6.1.7.RELEASE'
```

*Design wise we like our model classes in a project completely independent of UI or persistent technologies like hibernate. So that these model classes can be used in variety of different projects without any additional dependencies. And we achieved this with grails so far by creating a new class that extends actual model class in our library*

*Is there any way I can solve this problem, without modifying the base class?*

**In short, model classes (POJO) are now dependent on grails framework, whereas in earlier versions they were not.**

Comment: I doubt, your question in that answer will get much exposure.  Why not create a new question and refrence this answer there?